# Why can I not do methodThatReturnsIterator().next().length()?

Tags: java, string, iterator

For some reason, this doesn't work

```
    import java.util.*;

 public class SetExample
    {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(set().next().length());

}

public static Iterator set()
{
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "fableeblee", "cacao", "pablo", "thelma", "hepatitis"));
    Iterator<String> itr = arr.iterator();
    System.out.println(itr.next().length());
    return itr;
}   
}
```

The one line in main gives me a "cannot find symbol error", but a method similar to it in the set() method works. Why is this? It works perfectly fine in main when I remove the .length(), but with it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `set` has a return type of `Iterator`, not `Iterator<String>`, so when you receive an `Iterator` from the method's return, the machine cannot know what is inside of it, and thus `length` cannot be used on a general `Object`.

To fix this, add `Iterator<String>` as the return type instead of `Iterator`.

To clarify, this is essentially encapsulation at work. Methods outside of `set` do not know what goes on inside of it, only that it returns an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a raw iterator, and the `length()` method is undefined for its elements. Change your `set()` method to return `Iterator<String>`.